# How do I pull data from mysql and assign it to corresponding values

Tags: c#, mysql, list, winforms

Good Day.
I have a stock list in mysql database

I then have a windows form where i can allocate stock to a certain job, i do this by pulling all from my parts list in mysql and checking if the item selected by the user is in stock, i then add that item to a list using listbox.Items.Add(myitem). In also ass the quantity the user wants to a different list.
When I allocate the stock to a job i create one string separated by ',' and store that to mysql and the same with my quantites resulting is a parts string that looks like: 'PART001,PART002,PART003' and my quantities like: '2,1,3'.
I then add that to a request list which the admin needs to approve.

My problem comes in where the request form is loaded, I pull these parts and quantity lists from mySql and split them wit myString.Split(',');
And I then just add them to another listbox, HOWEVER when i get the quantities that my stock table has available, I loop over the part numbers and pull the quantities but if I for example have my first part as item 3 in my stock table and my second item as my 1st item in my stock list, it will assign item 1's quantity to my item 3. So basically my loop does not assign the right values.

Here is my code for checking the values

```
 ListBox lb = PartsListBox;
        ListBox lbq = PartsQuanListBox;
        String query = "SELECT * FROM parts WHERE partnum = '"+PartsSelectCb.Text.Trim()+"'";
        String partnum = "N/A";
        int quan = 0;

        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conString);
        con.Open();

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            partnum = (String)dr["partnum"];
        }
        con.Close();
        if(PartsSelectCb.Text == partnum)
        {
            quan = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            if (quan > 0)
            {
                if (!lb.Items.Contains(PartsSelectCb.Text.Trim()))
                {
                    lb.Items.Add(PartsSelectCb.Text.Trim());
                    lbq.Items.Add(textBox1.Text.Trim());
                }
            }
        }
```

And here is my code for inserting those values into my request table

```
private void SendRequest()
    {
        String dte = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

        String g = "";
        String h = "";

        String a = "";
        String b = "";
        if (PartsListBox.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in PartsListBox.Items)
            {
                g += item.ToString() + ",";
            }
            h = g.Substring(0, g.Length - 1);
        }
        if (PartsQuanListBox.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var itemt in PartsQuanListBox.Items)
            {
                a += itemt.ToString() + ",";
            }
            b = a.Substring(0, a.Length - 1);
        }
        String query = "INSERT INTO partsbook VALUES (NULL,'" + h + "','" + b + "','"
                                    + ReqTxt.Text.Trim() + "','" + userN + "','" + dte + "','" +""+"','"+ "REQUEST" + "')";
        MySqlConnection dataCon = new MySqlConnection(conString);
        dataCon.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, dataCon);
        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            pmf.CheckRequests();
            this.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception r)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR :" + r.Message.ToString());
        }
        dataCon.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("REQUEST SENT");
        this.Close();
    }
```

Then on the request side

```
private void GetStock()
    {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM parts";

        String qtys = "";

        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conString);
        con.Open();

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            String nme = (String)dr["partnum"];
            
            foreach(var item in UPartsListBox.Items)
            {
                if(item.ToString() == nme)
                {
                    int q = (int)dr["qty"];
                    qtys += q.ToString() + ",";
                    
                }
            }
        }
        con.Close();
        string[] words = qtys.Split(',');
        foreach(var word in words)
        {
            if(word != "")
            {
                SPartsQuanListBox.Items.Add(word);
            }
        }
    }
```

User Request:
[image]

Admin View:
[image]

Stock Table:
[image]

Comment: Rethink your database design and avoid storing comma separated strings as column values in database. Example: you should have a table with `jobid`, `partid` and `partqty` column to store the parts and quantities for a job...

Comment: Have you tried to use `entity framework`?

Comment: Do you know DataGridView?